# Reporting Services 2005 Model using WCF Service for data

Tags: wcf, reportingservices-2005

I am trying to use WCF Services as models for SQL Server Reporting Services 2005 reports. I can do this if I design the reports in the designer but cannot do it for a Reporting Model project which I think I need to make reports in the Report Builder.

My full requirement is to have a report builder that the users can use building reports based on DTOs supplied from my WCF service.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you can't do this.

I've gone for Dex Express XtraReports which seem to be more powerful. I'm using their designer components to make a Report Designer application - which I shall customise to integrate completely with the application - save/new/edit all handled by my code should make the experience more pleasent for the user.

It seems SSRS just isn't ready for user designed reports based on .NET objects yet.